# Why UIPopoverPresentationController resizes its content view?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller, popover

I have tried presenting a view controller in a popover using the old (iOS 7) and new (iOS 8) ways, yet when my VC is presented in the popover it has some extra space on the side because its frame's size is being set to 13 pt wider. Why?

**More details**:

It appears fine in the iOS7 simulator (when written the old way).

I have realized that the 13 pt is probably the size of the arrow (when you force the arrow to be Up or Down then it adds the 13 pt to the height instead of the width).

I did some further inspection (by setting a breakpoint in the `setFrame:` of my view) and found that there is a `UIPopoverPresentationController` method `presentationTransitionWillBegin` which calls `setFrame:` with the bad frame. After reading the [UIPopoverPresentationController Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014327) I learned that an instance of this class is created and managed by `UIKit` when you present the popover. Well, why `UIKit` are you trying to resize my view to include the arrow?

**For Reference**

By the "old way" I mean I override the method `contentSizeForViewInPopover` of the view controller being presented and then present it with

```
self.popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:aViewController];
[self.popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:rect
                                        inView:anInView
                      permittedArrowDirections:popoverArrowDirection
                                      animated:animated];
```

By the "new way" I mean

```
viewController.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(50.0f, 50.0f);
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];

UIPopoverPresentationController *presentationController = [viewController popoverPresentationController];
presentationController.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight;
presentationController.sourceView = aSourceView;
presentationController.sourceRect = aFrame;
```

**My current workaround**

I don't allow my view to be resized by the `UIPopoverPresentationController` or any controller for that matter.

```
@interface FixedSizeView : UIView
@end

@implementation FixedSizeView {
    CGSize size;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        size = frame.size;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (CGSizeEqualToSize(size, frame.size) || CGSizeEqualToSize(CGSizeZero,size)) {
        [super setFrame:frame];
    }
}
```

Comment: Banging my head against the wall with this one. Instead of changing the arrow direction and moving the popover, it is unnecessarily resized. This is driving me crazy, and your solution doesn't work for me... did you find out anything further?

Comment: Unfortunately no, this workaround became the long-term solution.